# Different style for last item of each list column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using CSS to divide a list in three different columns.
Every item of the list has a bottom border. Now I want to hide the bottom border from every last item of the columns.

I don't know how many items would be in the list, so it would not be possible to check for every second/thrid item with CSS.

Is there any other way to adress the last item of a column?

Here's my code:

```css
.list-col-3 {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
.list-col {
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5rem;
    column-gap: 1.5rem;
}
.list-col li {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
.list-unstyled {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.card_post {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b0afaf;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled list-col list-col-3">
 <li class="card_post">
  <h2 class="card-title">
   <span>Title</span>
  </h2>
  <div class="card-text">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class="card_post">
  <h2 class="card-title">
   <span>Title</span>
  </h2>
  <div class="card-text">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class="card_post">
  <h2 class="card-title">
   <span>Title</span>
  </h2>
  <div class="card-text">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class="card_post">
  <h2 class="card-title">
   <span>Title</span>
  </h2>
  <div class="card-text">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class="card_post">
  <h2 class="card-title">
   <span>Title</span>
  </h2>
  <div class="card-text">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class="card_post">
  <h2 class="card-title">
   <span>Title</span>
  </h2>
  <div class="card-text">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Cant you split your ul into 3 columns and fill each of these columns with your li`s?

Comment: No, I need to use a single <ul>

Comment: I mean keep 1 ul and have 3 <li> into it. Each <li> will be 1 column and you can further fill this <li> with another list which will represent each Item of your coulmn.

Comment: Can the answer have js or jquery?

Comment: @CataJohn unfortunately I've to use the layout from above :(

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO yes, that would be ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the whole list and calculate how many rows it contains by dividing the length by 3 (number of columns)

Then add a for loop to iterate over the las 3 element of each column and add a class i create with the name `last`

Hope this helps

```js
var list= $('.list-unstyled li');
var rows = list.length/3;;

//Adapt rows when no multiples of 3
if(list.length % 3 != 0)
  rows = Math.round(rows);

for(var i=0;i<=rows;i++){
  last = (i+1)*rows-1;
  if(list[last] == undefined)//Validate if rows no multiples of 3
    last = (i+1)*rows-2;
  list[last].classList.add("last");
}
```

```css
.list-col-3 {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}

.list-col {
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1.5rem;
  column-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.list-col li {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.list-unstyled {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.card_post {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b0afaf;
}

.last{
border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled list-col list-col-3">
  <li class="card_post">
    <h2 class="card-title">
      <span>Title</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card_post">
    <h2 class="card-title">
      <span>Title</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card_post">
    <h2 class="card-title">
      <span>Title</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card_post">
    <h2 class="card-title">
      <span>Title</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card_post">
    <h2 class="card-title">
      <span>Title</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: This solution is obviously nicer and cleaner, I would suggest this one instead of mine whenever possible.

Comment: Just a hint: The script only works if you could divide the items by 3. If not, there will be an error in the script.

Comment: I think i know why, ill try to fix it in an hour

Comment: not yet, now it adds the `.last` to the second last of the column. the items in the cols are these: 3|4|3. the first is correct. the last two not.

Comment: how you make them in 3|4|3. On your original layout you gave a 3|3|3 i assume you order them so if you remove 2 items you end up with 4|2|2

Comment: Can you maybe explain the possible scenarios. i am thinking for 3,4 and 5 items

Comment: In the current case I've 10 items in the whole list. Other list have 9,12,6... whatever. the height of each item is different. I guess that's the reason for the different number of items per column.

Comment: Yes but i am trying to fin d the loggic of the different scenarios so i can make an universal algorithm. My question is how you end up with 3|4|3 and not 4|3|3 or 3|3|4

Comment: I guess it's CSS. I've no influence over the items per column

Comment: can i maybe see a live example?

Comment: it's on a local machine. i will try to copy the code to codepen. but I'm on the way an need some time

Answer (score 2):

A possible pure CSS solution would be to make a sort of overlay to cover up the borders by giving it `position: absolute` and have it cover up the bottom ~30 pixels or so. This obviously won't work if the list doesn't have a solid color as background or if the `li`s can differ in `height` by any significant amount.

Here's what it would look like:

```css
.list-col-3 {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}

.list-col {
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1.5rem;
  column-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.list-col li {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.list-unstyled {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.card_post {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b0afaf;
}

.hide-border {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid red;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled list-col list-col-3">
  <li class="card_post">
    <h2 class="card-title">
      <span>Title</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card_post">
    <h2 class="card-title">
      <span>Title</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card_post">
    <h2 class="card-title">
      <span>Title</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card_post">
    <h2 class="card-title">
      <span>Title</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card_post">
    <h2 class="card-title">
      <span>Title</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card_post">
    <h2 class="card-title">
      <span>Title</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <div class="hide-border">I hide borders</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, but in your example the last two items in the second and third colum still have a bottom border. I think that would only work if all items are the same in height. But that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: @Cray I edited my code snippet to cover all three lines, but yeah, I thought so, however I still wanted to suggest it, in case it would work for you.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO yep, very hacky indeed haha.